# Where did the Config Editor go in Thunderbird 52.1.1 on Ubuntu 17.04?

Tags: thunderbird, 17.04

It used to be possible to find it in either **Tools** > **Options** > **Advanced** > **General** > **Config Editor** or **Preferences** > **Advanced** > **General** > **Config Editor**.

How can I open it now?

- Tools:

  [image]
- Preferences:

  [image: Thunderbird Preferences without Config Editor]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turn off your Thunderbird and open `~/.thunderbird/<your_profile>/prefs.js`.

Look for

```
user_pref("mail.preferences.advanced.selectedTabIndex", 3);
```

and delete it (or set it to `0` [which is the default value](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Mail_and_news_settings)).

Generally, look for `preferences` in `prefs.js` and find out which line is the culprit.

---

Thanks to [mook765](https://askubuntu.com/users/590937/mook765).

Comment: Look's like setting the value to `0` should do it. I think this setting is used to remember the last opened sub-tab in  the `Advanced`-tab, so setting the value to `0` should open the sub-tab which holds the `config editor`-button...

Answer (score 4):

For me there is a "Config Editor..." button in the *Preferences* window if I select "Advanced" (on TB 52.1.1).

*Edit:*

The "Advanced" tab has four sub tabs:

- General
- Data Choices
- Network & Disk Space
- Certificates

In the screenshot above you have the "Certificates" sub tab open. Click "General", and you'll hopefully see the "Config Editor..." button.

Comment: Looks like the OP is missing the tabs in the `Advanced`-section, the screenshot shows only the contents of the `Certificates`-tab, but there should appear several tabs in the `Advanced`-section, the button for the config-editor is in the `General`-tab in the `Advanced`-section.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, @mook765. I just edited my answer. (There is something wrong with the UI, so it's currently not obvious that those tab labels are clickable.)

Comment: I'm afraid that will not help as the sub-tabs to choose are not displayed. I think the OP has a corrupted profile and should backup his profile-folder  and create a fresh profile. Probably the problem occurred due to changes in the config-editor. BTW, we can edit the config-file with a text editor, the file to edit is `~.thunderbird/<your_profile>/prefs.js`, Thunderbird should not run while doing that. We can find out the location of the profile with `Help > Troubleshooting Information`.

Comment: @mook765: Actually the sub-tabs are displayed just as well (or just as bad) in the OP's screenshot as they are for me. It's the first line below the icons. So there probably is some kind of bug, but even if it's not obvious, the labels are clickable.

Comment: You are right, know I see them too, they just don't look like tabs...

Comment: @mook765 1. Actually, pref.js is exactly what I was looking for! 2. I've already checked all the "tabs" (including General) --- there is no Config Editor there.

Comment: @mook765 I've found the culprit: it was `user_pref("mail.preferences.advanced.selectedTabIndex", 3);` sitting in my `prefs.js`.