# Thunderbird config Editor missing

Tags: thunderbird

I'm using Ubuntu 18.04 LTS and the latest update of Thunderbird.

I'm getting question marks at the end of sentences when I double space.  I know the issue can be fixed by changing "strictly mime" in the configuration editor to "true." Unfortunately I cannot get to "Config Editor" following the links to "Advanced."  It's simply does not appear.  Is there an answer to my dilemma?

Comment: The answer below should work, if you can't see the tabs you may have a problem with your color-scheme. Take a close look, the tabs should work even if they don't look like tabs. [Here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1064216/possible-to-set-thunderbird-to-not-mark-messages-as-read-by-default/1064241#1064241) an example of a similar problem, the user didn't see the tabs.

Comment: [This question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/924192/where-did-the-config-editor-go-in-thunderbird-52-1-1-on-ubuntu-17-04?rq=1) is almost the same as yours.

Answer (score 3):

This is really a little bit hidden.

go to `Edit`-->`Preferences`-->`Advanced`-->`General`--> `Config Editor`:

[image]